# Self intersection in a simple polygon

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Suppose I have a simple polygon whose vertices are $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ each $p_i \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose now I pick two distincts vertices $p_i,p_j, i\neq j$ Is there some algorithm I can use to test for intersections between the segment $\overline{p_i p_j}$ and some edge of the polygon?

You can assume an half edge data structure is used for the polygon and the edge $\overline{p_i p_j}$ has to be inserted, so I'm looking for a quick test I can do before inserting a possible invalid edge. The polygon isn't necessarily convex.

Comment: Are the $p_i$'s in the order they appear when you traverse the perimeter of the polygon?

Comment: Yes, and my current guess is to define the segment equation $\overline{p_i p_j}$ and for each vertex of the polygon, except $p_i$ and $p_j$, test if they are on the left/right/front/back the segment. This algorithm is linear in the number of vertices, not sure there's anything better than this.

Comment: @user8469759 If I understand your problem correctly, you want to determine whether there is an intersection of your edge with the polygonal chain and not how many edges of that chain it intersects. In that case, there are instances that require checking $\Omega(n)$ edges, so you cannot do better there. It might be possible to create a data-structure with small edge-insertion cost that can check whether a new edge intersects in $o(n)$, would that solve your problem?

Comment: Can you suggest any of those data structures that would potentially speed up the process?

Comment: Well, if the polygon is convex then the answer is always "no intersection".  If you have a decomposition of the polygon into convex polygons, and $p_i$ and $p_j$ both belong to the same convex polygon in this decomposition, the answer is likewise "no intersection".  But building/maintaining such a decomposition is not a complete solution because if they belong to different convex polygons, the answer could be "yes" or "no".

Comment: Long story short there's no better solution then exhaustive testing, given my statement of the problem.

Comment: @user8469759 No, not currently, at least. But that is the only type of improvement over the $O(n)$ solution I think you can get, so you may wish to edit your question to mention whether such a solution would help you. Otherwise, the answer is simply to use the $O(n)$ solution.

Comment: There's no actually issue, but I need to implement this functionality and I was just wondering if there was any smart way of doing it. Thank you.